# How to display textbox trailing elipsis

Tags: windows-phone-7

I need to display name as dot..
ex:"please help me" as "Please help..." like that in wp7

Comment: Make sure you're still following the wp7 paradigms when you use this. For example, titles will often extend past the visible screen, some lists which have text will do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
```

Source: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.texttrimming%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)